# REST call to Azure service bus queues

Tags: rest, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

Can we perform REST call to publish and consume messages from Azure service bus queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Check the [Azure Service Bus REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/).

For instance: the [Receive and Delete Message (Destructive Read)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/receive-and-delete-message-destructive-read) operation ...

> ... receives a message from a queue or subscription, and removes the message from that queue or subscription in one atomic operation.